# Dart Phone class search with flutter_contacts

Tags: flutter, dart, contacts

I created a function (using `flutter_contacts`) that searches contacts on my Phone based on a given contact cell number (input - cellnumber) :

```
Contact? contact = contacts.firstWhereOrNull((c) => c.phones.contains(Phone(cellnumber)));
```

It works completely ok when I search for a number without "+" sign (e.g. `12345`) and the contact in the contact list has a number without "+" (e.g. `12345`).
But it doesn't work when I search for a number with "+" sign (e.g. `+12345`) and the contact has a number with plus (e.g. `+12345`).

Anyone knows why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the code](https://github.com/QuisApp/flutter_contacts/blob/master/lib/properties/phone.dart) you will see that for the `Phone` class to be equal to another, there needs to be more components to match than just the phone number.

So to check for phone numbers only, you need to roll your own coparison:

```
Contact? contact = contacts.firstWhereOrNull((c) => c.phones.any((phone) => phone.number == cellNumber);
```

If this still does not match, print all the contacts to debug it. I have no idea what your contact list contains or why it would not match.

There is a `normalizedNumber` property, maybe you need to use that instead to figure out if someone used formatting like "+1 (234) 567-8900".

Comment: Yes, it appeared that all phone numbers on iPhone are not homogeneous. I extracted a list of the, and this is an example of one: 
[Phone(number=+1 (617) 470-6118, normalizedNumber=, label=PhoneLabel.mobile, customLabel=, isPrimary=false)]
By any chance, does anyone know how to adjust the code (especially the extract of Phone - c.phones) to delete all unnecessary symbols ( "(""," ","-"....) and match just the numbers of cellphones?

Comment: But normalized formatting works only for Android as I understand